# How to replicate ONLY the key structure of a nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, copy

Say I have a dictionary as the following

```sh
{'g_g': {'cube': array([...]),
         'factorization': array([...]),
         'renormalization': array([...]),
         'square': array([...])},
 'q_g': {'12': {'cube': array([...]),
                'factorization': array([...]),
                'renormalization': array([...]),
                'square': array([...])},
         '21': {'cube': array([...]),
                'factorization': array([...]),
                'renormalization': array([...]),
                'square': array([...])}},
 'q_q': {'cube': array([...]),
         'factorization': array([...]),
         'renormalization': array([...]),
         'square': array([...])}}
```

How could I copy all the keys (with the structure) of the dictionary and set the innermost keys' values to `None`? The structure can be different so it is better to let the code recognize which keys are the innermost. I know `deepcopy` could do it, but it would copy the values as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `deepcopy` and then manually reassign the innermost value to `None`?

Comment: @JohnGordon I may not necessarily know its structure and I would like the program to figure it out by it self.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to delete the array part of the dictionaries, you can use the following after using `deepcopy`.

```
# Suppose ar is the dictionary you get after using deepcopy
def func(ar):
    for i in ar:
        if type(ar[i]) != dict:
            ar[i] = None
        else:
            func(ar[i])
```